# multiple variables using foreach as?

Tags: php, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to fetch YouTube thumbnails and video id's using the API v3 and echo them into HTML, however I need to echo two variables at the same time. At the moment I have the following:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=12&playlistId=UUDWdi7vjr3ac_z_VMMeiL_Q&key=*************************';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
if ((preg_match_all("/\"videoId\":\s*\"(.+)\"/", $data, $video_get) ) && (preg_match_all("/\"title\":\s*\"(.+)\"/", $data, $title_get) ) ) {
    foreach (($video_get[1] as $videoid) && foreach ($title_get[1] as $title ) ){
        echo ("<div id=\"video-thumb\" class=\"col-sm-6\"><img id=\"video-thumb-320180\" src=\"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/'.$videoid.'/mqdefault.jpg\"><div class=\"video-hover\"><img class=\"play-hover\" src=\"images/play.png\"></div><h2 class=\"video-title\"><i><a href=\"https://youtube.com/watch?v='.$videoid.'\">'.$title.'</a></h2></i></div>");
        }
    }
else {
    echo ("Error fetching uploads!")
}
?>
```

However after trying this it seems I cannot use foreach as && foreach as. What's the solution here?

Comment: It would help to see a sample of the `file_get_contents()` output.

Comment: Its not possible. Try nested loops instead

Comment: Actually, that API returns JSON. You don't need to `preg_match` anything. Just use `json_decode()`.

Comment: As stated on the comment to the other answer. I'm very new to PHP. How does the json format help me and how would I get my video and title elements from it?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're trying to do `preg_match()` ... but that data is json, just `json_decode()` it and you're done.

```
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=12&playlistId=UUDWdi7vjr3ac_z_VMMeiL_Q&key=AIzaSyBYG6nKkdddYT2NXg987kljPrKqsCVXcNQ';
/** data is in an array **/
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
foreach($data['items'] as $row) {
    echo ("
    <div id=\"video-thumb\" class=\"col-sm-6\">
        <img id=\"video-thumb-320180\" src=\"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/".$row['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']."/mqdefault.jpg\">
        <div class=\"video-hover\">
            <img class=\"play-hover\" src=\"images/play.png\">
        </div>
        <h2 class=\"video-title\">
            <i><a href=\"https://youtube.com/watch?v=".$row['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']."\">" . $row['snippet']['title']."</a></i>
        </h2>
    </div>");
}
```

> response (from documentation)

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
  "etag": etag,
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "prevPageToken": string,
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": integer,
    "resultsPerPage": integer
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
      "etag": etag,
      "id": string,
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": datetime,
        "channelId": string,
        "title": string,
        "description": string,
        "thumbnails": {
          (key): {
            "url": string,
            "width": unsigned integer,
            "height": unsigned integer
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": string,
        "playlistId": string,
        "position": unsigned integer,
        "resourceId": {
          "kind": string,
          "videoId": string,
        }
      },
      "contentDetails": {
        "videoId": string,
        "startAt": string,
        "endAt": string,
        "note": string
      },
      "status": {
        "privacyStatus": string
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to PHP. How does the json format help me and how would I get my video and title elements from it?

Comment: json stands for .. JavaScript Object Notation. You will either see that or xml for most apis, it's extremely easy to convert it into workable code.

Comment: JSON is basically a flattened (serialized) object or array. It's how most APIs return request data.

Comment: I recommend that you read this page for the full documentation, https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/

Comment: here is the relevant documentation about json_decode http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: I used your above code and got a 500 server error? I changed the echo to just echo $row['contentDetails']['videoId']; and still 500 error. **edit the $data['items'] is the cause of the sever error,.

Comment: I've updated it based on the documentation, so it's definitely working now. That being said I do recommend that you get familiar with json as you will see it lots.

Comment: Yeah I've already started reading into it, thanks for your help! The sample code from the google website returned a 500 as well? I'm going to see if PHP needs an update but I doubt it.

Comment: did you run my updated sample? It ran on my machine.